What was the fate of Mr. Bunting?
In the animated film The Imaginary, the primary villain, Mr. Bunting, undergoes a very convoluted series of events.
To wit,

 he first accidentally consumes the girl who is implied to be his original imaginary friend, then turns into a ball of smoke, which shrinks before turning into a photograph of himself (similar to the ones that appear in the library); his image in the photograph then ages before the photograph itself is consumed in flames and disappears.

What exactly happened to Mr. Bunting here, and what was his final fate?
